# delphi code does not connect me to irc server

Tags: delphi

hello am doing a program in delphi console, xe2 delphi and indy for using sockets and the problem is that I have all the code done but when I connect to the server I receive no response to the ping pong.

the code is as follows:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils, idTCPClient;

var
  irc: TIdTCPClient;
  code: string;

begin
  try

    irc := TIdTCPClient.Create(nil);
    irc.Host := 'irc.freenode.net';
    irc.Port := 6667;
    irc.Connect;

    irc.Socket.Write('NICK tester');
    irc.Socket.Write('USER tester 1 1 1 1');
    irc.Socket.Write('JOIN #tester');

    if irc.Socket.Connected = True then
    begin
      Writeln('Yeah');
      while (1 = 1) do
      begin
        code := irc.Socket.ReadString(9999);
        if not(code = '') then
        begin
          Writeln(code);
        end;
      end;
    end
    else
    begin
      Writeln('Nay');
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;

end.
```

anyone can help me?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not using the `TIdIRC` component?

Answer (score 2):

You are not sending a CRLF after each command you send.  Use `TIdIOHander.WriteLn()` instead of `TIdIOHandler.Write()`.

Also, your call to `TIdIOHandler.ReadString()` will not exit until exactly 9999 bytes have been received.  That is not what you actually want to happen.  IRC is a line-based protocol.  You should be using `TIdIOHandler.ReadLn()` instead of `TIdIOHandler.ReadString()`.

Try something more like this instead:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils, idTCPClient;

var
  irc: TIdTCPClient;
  code: string;
begin
  try
    irc := TIdTCPClient.Create(nil);
    try
      irc.Host := 'irc.freenode.net';
      irc.Port := 6667;

      try
        irc.Connect;
      except
        Writeln('Nay');
        Exit;
      end;

      Writeln('Yeah');

      irc.IOHandler.WriteLn('NICK tester');
      irc.IOHandler.WriteLn('USER tester 1 1 1 1');
      irc.IOHandler.WriteLn('JOIN #tester');

      repeat
        code := irc.IOHandler.ReadLn;
        Writeln('[Recv] ' + code);
        if TextStartsWith(code, 'PING ') then
        begin
          Fetch(code);
          irc.IOHandler.WriteLn('PONG ' + code);
          Writeln('[Sent] PONG ' + code);
        end;
      until False;
    finally
      irc.Free;
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

With that being said, you should be using the `TIdIRC` component instead.  Try this:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils, idIRC, idContext, idGlobal;

procedure IrcRaw(ASelf: Pointer; ASender: TIdContext; AIn: Boolean; const AMessage: String);
begin
  Writeln(iif(AIn, '[Recv] ', '[Sent] ') + AMessage);
end;

var
  irc: TIdIRC;
  m: TMethod;
begin
  try
    irc := TIdIRC.Create(nil);
    try
      irc.Host := 'irc.freenode.net';
      irc.Port := 6667;
      irc.Nickname := 'tester';
      irc.Username := 'tester';

      m.Code := @IrcRaw;
      m.Data := irc;
      irc.OnRaw := TIdIRCRawEvent(m);

      try
        irc.Connect;
      except
        Writeln('Nay');
        Exit;
      end;

      Writeln('Yeah');

      irc.Join('#tester');

      repeat
        Sleep(10);
      until SomeCondition;
    finally
      irc.Free;
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```